# Branch is ahead of origin by more than one commit after merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I had two branches that looked like this:

```
    X--X [origin/master, master]
.../ 
   \         
    ----X--X--X--X--X--X [origin/x, x]
```

then I merged `x` into `master` so now I have this:

```
       [origin/master]
    X--X------------------X [master]
.../                     /
   \                    /
    ----X--X--X--X--X--X [origin/x, x]
```

Now when I `git status` I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 7 commits.
  (use "git push" ...)
...
```

Why is it 7 commits? From the picture (which I drew looking at `git log --graph`) it seems it should be ahead by 1 commit. Other 6 commits are for branch `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Other 6 commits are for branch x

Aha, that's just where you're wrong.  Remember, a branch in Git is *not* a chain of commits, the way you are thinking of it. It is *one* commit. Everything else is just commits that are *reachable* from that one commit, by walking backwards along the parent chain.

Well, a merge commit, such as you have just created, has *two* parents, one of which is the branch commit that just got merged in. So after the merge, all the commits that were previously reachable only from `x` are now also reachable from `master` (because `x` is now one of the parents of `master`, which is the merge commit).

So all Git is doing here is counting how many commits are now reachable from `master` that are not reachable from `origin/master`, like this:

```
       [origin/master]    7
    X--X------------------X [master]
.../                     /
   \                    /
    ----X--X--X--X--X--X [origin/x, x]
        1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Git doesn't care about the *topology* that makes that be so; it's just reporting a number.

So the number reported by Git might seem unintuitive, but in fact it is perfectly accurate. And it's a useful number! Git is rightly reporting that if you were now to push, causing `origin/master` to move up to `master`, `origin/master` would then be able to reach 7 commits that it presently cannot reach, and the remote repository would acquire 7 commits that it currently does not have.

Comment: Is there a reason for this? Because as you mentioned this is unintuitive. Ahead means ahead, not reachable!

Comment: I didn't say Git's messages were phrased particularly beautifully. On the contrary, a lot of the names and terms that Git uses in talking to you are misleading. I've never liked "ahead" and "behind". (In fact I don't like _anything_ about the way `git status` talks.) Still, I've tried to show you that "ahead" does make a certain sense: `master` does indeed reach 7 commits that `origin/master` doesn't yet know about, so in terms of progress (or size?), `master` is 7 commits "ahead".

Comment: @ParSal If your mind is stuck in linear history, the behavior may be "unintuitive", but as soon as you get acquainted with branchy and mergy history, you will appreciate the way in which Git counts commits.

Comment: Concerning the last sentence "the remote repository would acquire 7 commits that it currently does not have": Either I don't understand correctly what you mean, or this is not necessarily true if branch x has an upstream branch. In this case the remote repository already has (in the way I understand "has") the commits which you numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, only 7 is missing. So the repository acquires only 1 commit.

Comment: @NerdOnTour Yes, I suppose a premise of the question was that the branch `x` was up to date with its upstream before the merge. Good point! Maybe I meant "the remote repository's `master` branch" or similar.